# loading of Cross-origin images from Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cors

I'm building a site that frequently loads pictures from facebook. 
I've been trying to use this tutorial from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image#Example.3A_Storing_an_image_from_a_foreign_origin), which works fine locally, but when I go live, facebook does not allow me to access images like that and returns:

"Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy."

Is there any way to work around this problem (that does not involve buffering the image my own server)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably have to have their API key to do that. Consult the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

If you want to access the cross domain content which you can access from the browser, use CURL from PHP and make calls to the site with it. I will update the answer with the simple php curl script. You can use it to download images, it's like a proxy :)

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['url'];

function request($url) {  
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    $response = curl_exec($c);
    $responseInfo = curl_getinfo($c);
    curl_close($c);
    if (intval($responseInfo['http_code']) == 200) {
        return $response;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

echo request($url);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain how the API key could help here? I mean, usually accessing stuff from a remote domain (here, the pixels of that image) is not allowed unless CORS is enabled by facebook. Your link only talks about the Graph API but this works fine already. The thing is that I'm trying to download the image using localStorage.setItem, thus I assume I either have to do something with img.crossOrigin, or it does not work at all.
However, I can't find anything on the web if this CORS is supported or not.

Comment: If you want to access the cross domain content which you can access from the browser, use CURL from PHP and make calls to the site with it. I will update the answer with the simple php curl script.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to work around this problem (that does not involve buffering the image my own server)?

No. The images need to be on a server you control (or that you have enough influence over whomever does for permissions to be granted). You can't set CORS headers on Facebook's servers, so the images will not be accessible cross-domain while they are hosted there.